# .htaccess rule for 301 redirect of URL with misspelt parameter value to URL with correct parameter value

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have an application running on a set of servers that fetches a URL from another server that I am running.

This URL that is being fetched consists of a hard coded URL with misspelt URL parameters. I would like to fix that by creating a .htaccess rule for a 301 redirect to the correct URL on my target server instead of changing the application and uploading it to all my other servers.

I am assuming I could do this by creating a RedirectRule using regex, but I suck at that.

Here is what I am trying to achieve :

```
http://www.example.com/some-page/?param1=exparam1&param2=misspeltparam&param3=exparam3
```

The above URL should redirect to :

```
http://www.example.com/some-page/?param1=exparam1&param2=correctparam&param3=exparam3
```

In the above example `param2=misspeltparam` and `param2=correctparam` (i.e. both the parameter name and value) are constants. everything else is dynamic.

Also, the spelling mistake will occur only for `param2`, just in case that was not obvious from the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following code should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&param2=)misspeltparam(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}?%1correctparam%2 [R=301,L]
```